# PHP json response not working

Tags: php, json

I am doing an ajax update.  I just want a response of success or failure so I know how to handle some things in the front end.  Problem is it isn't working.  Brand new to all of this.

```
$('.delete-template-popup .confirm').on('click', function() {
    var templateName = $('.loaded-template-name').html();

    var templateArray = {};

    templateArray.templateName = templateName;

    var JSONObject = [templateArray];
    var templateJson = JSON.stringify(JSONObject);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/ds-layouts/public/delete-template.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: {"templatePHP" : templateJson},
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data)
            if (data.status == "success") {
                console.log(1)
            }
            // if (data.status == "success") {
            //  closePopup($('.delete-template-popup'));
            //  window.location.replace("http:////localhost/ds-layouts/public/manage-layouts.php");
            // } else {
            //  $('.delete-template-popup .error').show().html('An error occurred processing your request.  Please try again.  If this error persists contact blah.');
            // }                        
        }
    });
});
```

and the php

```
if ($flag) {
        //mysqli_commit($connection);
        if ($debug) {
            echo "pass";
            echo "\r\n";
        }
        //$_SESSION["message"] = "Template delete was successful.";
        //header('Content-Type: application/json');
        header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF8');
        echo json_encode(array('status' => 'success'));
    } else {
        if ($debug) {
            echo "fail";
            echo "\r\n";
        }
        //mysqli_rollback($connection);
        // header('Content-Type: application/json');
        // echo json_encode(array('status' => 'failure'));
    }
```

So the deal is I am getting into the if block of the php statment fine.  If I have the header part of the block I get all of my echo statements passed properly and I can read them in Chromes developer console.  The moment I uncomment the header statement nothing works.  This is for either one of $flag cases true or false.

I have this same type of script in another area and it works absolutely fine.  Don't mind the comments.  I was just commenting things out as a way to figure out where things were breaking.  That is how I determened the header was causing it.

Comment: The header must be before echo

Comment: Please remove commented out code

Comment: Wow...so simple.  Now I feel like an idiot.  I didn't know that one.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe adding the `dataType: "json",` to your AJAX request object will help?

Answer (score 0):

try this php

```
header('Content-Type: application/json'); //must be FIRST output. 
if ($flag) {

    //mysqli_commit($connection);
    if ($debug) {
        echo json_encode(array('debug' => 'pass'));
    }
    else
    {
        echo json_encode(array('status' => 'success'));
    }
} else {
    if ($debug) {
       echo json_encode(array('debug' => 'fail'));
    }
    else
    {
       //mysqli_rollback($connection);
       echo json_encode(array('status' => 'failure'));
    }
}
```

I've changed the debug blocks to return json, since turning on debug will break the ajax anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As the answer was posted as a comment I can't mark the answer as fixed.  I am going to mark this answer as the what fixed the issue:

"The header must be before echo –  user4035"

Thank you user4035 for letting me know about the header being before any echos aka before any printed form of html from the server...I should have known that.